# Which ways should I go Front-End firs or Back-end first in Project development?

Tags: project-management, setup-project

I want build an application by using the framework.
the application contains two parts: the Back-End and the Front-End.

Everybody who have experiences can suggest me which ways should I do?:

`Develop the Front-End first Or Develop the Back-End first`

Or give more tips on the start up project?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually start with the backend to get the major functionality implemented, but even so, it's pretty much inevitable that the frontend and backend will have to be developed at the same time at some point in the project.

People can say what they want about separating presentation and functionality, and that's a good principle, but the reality is that the presentation influences the functionality and vice versa.

You might get the backend mostly written, and then you make the frontend, but you will probably decide to change some things and end up working on both together.